# Adjust a one dimensional Bezier-Curve?

Tags: linear-algebra, curves, bezier-curve

I really need to adjust my one dimensional Bezier-Curve, but I don't know how.

I got this equation: 
$$
y = A(1-x)^3 + 3B(1-x)^2x + 3C(1-x)x^2 + Dx^3
$$
with the constants A,B,C,D which represent the $y$-value of my 4 control points.

But how can I make my y grow faster at the beginning? The end should be the same as before. 
I have no $x$-control-value in my equation to adjust that property.

Edit: My derivative at the beginning and at the end is equal zero. So:

y'(0)=0

y'(1)=0

I hope you understand my problem.

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Hint: Find the derivative at the beginning and adjust constants so that the value of the derivative is larger and thus $y$ grows faster at the beginning.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh Thank you, but my derivative is zero at the beginning!

Comment: Ok, then try to manipulate points that are of interest to you.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh What do you mean exactly with "manipulate" and what are those points of interest? I guess the first and second one. But the X-Koordinate has no impact.

Comment: I was having the idea that if you want your function to grow faster, then by finding the derivative you can see how it "grows" at any point. Because you want it to grow faster at the beginning then I tought that at these points you can adjust the derivative to grow more rapidly. I would sugest if you are using Matlab to try to use the cftool function to manipulate with the function for various constants. I will try it by myself and if I find something I will let you know.

Comment: Could you exactly define the region ($x$ values) where you would like the $y$ values to grow faster?

Comment: Evaluate $y$ at at $\sqrt x$.

Comment: @DinnoKoluh the x is from 0 to 1 and I want the function grow faster from 0 to 0.5 and grow slower from 0.5 to 1 to make the graph smooth.

Comment: @lhf Why should I evaluate y at sqrt(x) ?

Comment: $\sqrt x$ gets faster from $0$ to $0.5$ than $x$does..